# How to integrate Icontact in rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using rails 3.2.8 and want to integrate Icontact in my application. I gone through the following documentation(http://rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_icontact/0.4.3/frames). I got active support dependency error. So I used acts_as_icontact(0.3.0), which doesn't require any gem dependency. But still I'm getting same error

```
/home/dckap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@qtect/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- activesupport (LoadError)
```

Is there any way to use different version of active support?

Answer (score 1):

Read and follow the tutorial on [the homepage](https://github.com/SFEley/acts_as_icontact).